# Carousel like on revolut app

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement a carousel like on this video https://www.revolut.com/assets/media/ios1.76bac5.mp4 .Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve this in react native.I tried using this plugin https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel but I can only show 1 item.I want it to be like on revolut with preview.

Comment: I wonder if you could use react native snap carousel, but just set the background as transparent, then you would only see one item, not the sides of the other two.  I grabbed their demo repo and tweaked the code to do other stuff, so it might be possible.  You can always ask the snap carousel guys how to match revolut, they seem to get back to people.

Comment: I managed to create something similar but the problem is I can't set width of the item to be auto.I receive text bank names instead of just a number so some items can have a bigger width because of that.Setting it to a manual width will not work properly if there is an a text with a bigger width

Comment: I don’t fully understand, but it might be worth submitting a pull request to accomplish what you’re after, and they just might explain how to do it with their library. I’ve seen them do that for a number of people.

Comment: I did and tried some thing but in the end the plugin will have to be updated to allow an auto width item.